# is it possible to set text on wallpaper programmatically in android studio

Tags: android

i am developing an application that set specified wallpaper on specific date automatically. Actually i want to also set specific text on that specified wallpaper. i searched for it but did not find any solution. is it possible to set a text view in wallpaper? if it is possible then please help me to set text on wallpaper.

Comment: you can put the text which you want to set in an image. And that image you can set in your android xml as `android:thumbnail=@drawable/your_image_with_text`

Answer (score 1):

Actually u can set scheduled wallpaper using the alarm manager class to fire the intent and for the text use canvas or live wallpaper

```
// Button to set the Wallpaper
public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(
        WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
    new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

}